# How to add a property to a Table Adapter that can be bound to?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, tableadapter

I have a database table `TravelRequest` that contains, amongst other things, the fields `SignOffName` and `SignOffDate`. I have a table adapter `TravelRequestTable` based on this table. I have a DetailsView control which uses this via an ObjectDataSource. Should be all fairly standard stuff.

What I want to do is add a property called `SignOffNameDate` to the table adapter that combines the two fields *and* be able to bind to it in the DetailsView control. I want to do it programmatically rather than adding another column in the SQL because dealing with null values is tricky and depends on some other business rules.

This is what I tried:

```
public partial class TravelRequestDS
{
    public partial class TravelRequestRow
    {
        public string SignOffNameDate
        {
            get { return CombineNameDate(SignOffName, SignOffDate); }
        }
    }
}
```

This property works fine when I access it programmatically, but when I try bind to it in my aspx page:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView_TravelRequest" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False"
    DataKeyNames="TravelRequestID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource_TravelRequest">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SignOffNameDate"
                HeaderText="Sign Off" />
            ...
```

I get an System.Web.HttpException exception, "A field or property with the name 'SignOffNameDate' was not found on the selected data source."

Any ideas how I can do this? Is there an attribute I need to add to the property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objective is to display the combined result in a single non-editable field you can do it like this:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView_TravelRequest" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False"
    DataKeyNames="TravelRequestID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource_TravelRequest">
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sign Off" SortExpression="SignOffDate">               
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SignOffName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SignOffDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your table structure, change the default method that loads data into your adapter (usually called Fill), most likely you are doing a Select * From [TravelRequest] or selecting the individual fields, so what you could do is change your TableAdapter query select statement to something like

```
Select [YourCol1],[YourCol2], SignOffNameDate as Null From [TravelRequest]
```

Modifying the default query, and selecting SignOffNameDate as null will give you access to set this value

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your answer. By adding the dummy SignOffNameDate field in the SQL, the table adapter adds a property of that name in the generated code and I get a "The type 'TravelRequestDS.TravelRequestRow' already contains a definition for 'SignOffNameDate'" compiler error.

Comment: Is there something else I can do to override the property?

Comment: are you still using the class in the original post? You no longer need it.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't follow you. I need to use my CombineNameDate method to *programmatically* combine the two fields. If I remove the class, how specify the SignOffNameDate property using this method?

Comment: ok let me take that back, to make  things easy, why don't you select the fields you want to combine via the sql statement or is it something a little more complex than that, so instead of selecting null, could you select the two fields you need via sql and eliminate the need for you combine method?

Comment: For instance Select SignOffNameDate as [Field1] + ' ' + [Field2], I'm guessing a straight concat is wishful thinking or you wouldn't have asked this question in the first place

Comment: nevermind, I think I approached this in the completely wrong way and totally neglected the fact that you're using an objectdatasource, I'll ponder this one again, sorry for the confusion, I kept thinking SqlDataSource